# Ionic React: Implementing InAppPurchase 2 on React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework, react-hooks, ionic-native

I am trying to implement InAppPurchase 2 from https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase in Ionic React.

It seems that the ready event is never been called.

Here is my code:

```
....
import { IAPProduct, InAppPurchase2 as iap } from "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      await initInAppPurchase();
      setInitialized(true);
    }
    init();
  }, [])
  
  ....
}

export const initInAppPurchase = () => {
  if (isPlatform('android') || isPlatform('ios')) {

    iap.verbosity = iap.DEBUG;

    iap.register({
      id: "com.mysoftwares.posapp.test",
      alias: "Test",
      type: iap.NON_CONSUMABLE
    });

    iap.when("com.mysoftwares.posapp.test").updated((product: IAPProduct) => {
      if (product.owned)
        console.log('Product owned')
      else
        console.log('Product not owned')
    });

    iap.when("com.mysoftwares.posapp.test").approved(function (product: any) {
      product.finish();
    });

    iap.ready(() => {
      alert("Product ready!")
      let product = iap.get('Test');
      alert(product);
      if (product.canPurchase) {
        iap.order('Test');
      }
    })

    iap.refresh();
  }
}
```

Here is the log from debug verbose:

```
[store.js] DEBUG: state: com.mysoftwares.posapp.test -> registered
[store.js] DEBUG: store.trigger -> triggering action refreshed
InAppBilling[js]: setup ok
InAppBilling[js]: load ["com.mysoftwares.posapp.test"]
InAppBilling[js]: listener: {"type":"ready","data":{}} 
[store.js] DEBUG: store.trigger -> triggering action refresh-finished 
InAppBilling[js]: setup ok 
InAppBilling[js]: load ["com.mysoftwares.posapp.test","com.mysoftwares.posapp.test"] 
InAppBilling[js]: listener: {"type":"ready","data":{}} 
InAppBilling[js]: setup ok
InAppBilling[js]: load ["com.mysoftwares.posapp.test","com.mysoftwares.posapp.test","com.mysoftwares.posapp.test"]
InAppBilling[js]: listener: {"type":"ready","data":{}}
InAppBilling[js]: setup ok
```

I am using React Hooks. I have published my app in `Google Play Console` and have added the test product in `In-app Products` section inside `Google Play Console`. Currently my app is on `open testing phase`.

I have created an app before coded in pure `Apache Cordova` without `Ionic`, it works fine, but this in React is not.

What is wrong with my code? Please help...

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the following:

Install these in terminal

```
npm install @ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2
npm install cordova-plugin-purchase
```

This code in .tsx file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { InAppPurchase2 as iap, IAPProduct } from "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2";


const Home: React.FC = () => {

        //declare variables 
        const [productPrice, setPrice] = useState('')
        const [product, setProduct] = useState([]) as any

        //initiate initInAppPurchase function 
        useEffect(() => {
            const init = async () => {
                await initInAppPurchase();
            }
            init();

        }, []);

        //if on an ios or android device, then get product info 
        const initInAppPurchase = () => {
            if ((isPlatform('ios')) || (isPlatform('android'))) {
                iap.verbosity = iap.DEBUG;

                iap.register({
                    id: "com.test.test",
                    alias: "Test",
                    type: iap.NON_CONSUMABLE
                });

                iap.ready(() => {
                    let product = iap.get('Test');
                    setPrice(product.price)
                    setProduct(product)
                })

                iap.refresh();
            }
        }

        //if user clicks purchase button 
        const purchaseProduct = () => {
            if (product.owned) {
                alert('Product already owned, click restore button instead!')
            } else {
                iap.order('Test').then(() => {
                    iap.when("com.test.test").approved((p: IAPProduct) => {
                        //store product 
                        p.verify();
                        p.finish();
                    });
                })
                iap.refresh();
            }
        }

        //if user clicks retore or promo code button 
        const restore = () => {
                iap.when("com.test.test").owned((p: IAPProduct) => {
                    if (product.owned) {
                        //store product 
                    } else {
                        alert("You have not purchased this product before.")
                    }
                });
                iap.refresh();
  }

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonCard className="homeCards">
          <IonButton onClick={purchaseProduct}>Buy for {productPrice}</IonButton>
          <IonButton onClick={restore}>Restore</IonButton>
          <IonButton onClick={restore}>Promo code</IonButton>
      </IonCard>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

To test apple in app purchase on device:

- Had a developer account
- Created in app purchase in apple connect
- Added my email as a tester in apple connect
- Uploaded app onto phone from Xcode and purchases worked

To test android in app purchase on device:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

- Added above line of code to AdnroidManifest.xml file
- Had a developer account
- Uploaded the .aab or .apk file to internal testing on google play console and added my email as a tester
- Created in app purchase
- Uploaded app onto phone from Android Studio and purchases worked

Answer (score 1):

I am testing it on emulator which is dumb. On mobile devices, it works fine.